# Contact form won't submit after jQuery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, form-submit

I can't manage to make my form validate on the client side and to be submitted after that. Problem is probably in the submitting part of the code, because the validation part works if I remove submitting part. Can anyone help me please?
Here is my code:

```
var allowed_file_size = "5242880";
  var allowed_files = ['image/png', 'image/psd', 'image/jpeg', 'image/eps'];
  var border_color = "#036a96"; //initial input border color

  $("#contact_body").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    proceed = true;

    //simple input validation
    $($(this).find("input[data-required=true], textarea[data-required=true]")).each(function() {
      if (!$.trim($(this).val())) { //if this field is empty 
        $(this).css('border-color', 'red'); //change border color to red   
        proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
      }
      //check invalid email
      var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
      if ($(this).attr("type") == "email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))) {
        $(this).css('border-color', 'red'); //change border color to red   
        proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag              
      }
    }).on("input", function() { //change border color to original
      $(this).css('border-color', border_color);
    });

    //check file size and type before upload, works in modern browsers
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
      var total_files_size = 0;
      $(this.elements['my-file'].files).each(function(i, ifile) {
        if (ifile.value !== "") { //continue only if file(s) are selected
          if (allowed_files.indexOf(ifile.type) === -1) { //check unsupported file
            $("#push").html(ifile.name + " nije dozvoljen tip fajla!");
            proceed = false;
          }
          total_files_size = total_files_size + ifile.size; //add file size to total size
        }
      });
      if (total_files_size > allowed_file_size) {
        $("#push").html("Maksimalna velicina fajla je 5 MB!");
        proceed = false;
      }
    }
    if (proceed) {
      var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
      var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
      var form_data = new FormData(this); //Creates new FormData object

      $.ajax({ //ajax form submit
        url: post_url,
        type: request_method,
        data: form_data,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false
      }).done(function());
    }
  });
```

Comment: Would you mind submitting a jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Here is the hole code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b850b380b5062a8e7eca6ef0cf8e87e7     @thedayturns thank you for your effort

Answer (score 0):

From your code, in the `$.ajax` function call:

`}).done(function());`

This is incorrect syntax. The function needs a body. It should be `}).done(function() {});`

Comment: Thank you, but that still didn't solve my problem. I'm new at this, so if you need more information to solve my problem please let me now. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Think you might be missing the function body of the `done` callback, which causes a syntax error. It would have been easier to spot if you had opened your DEV console.

```
}).done(function());
```

is supposed to be

```
}).done(function() {} );
```

Comment: Thank you but that still didn't solve the problem. I've opened DEV console, but there is nothing there about my problem. Do I need to provide more information?